# How do I not allow a child item to leave within the parent in Nestable.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-nestable

For example, I have my item 1 and item 2, and both have child items. How do I not allow the children of item 1 to be moved to the children of item 2. Remembering that I need the children to be able to move between themselves and the parents as well, but the children can only move within their parent

I've tried using the groups but it didn't work, and also starting anothertable just with the children, but it didn't work either